# Trouble securing my wifi connection, setup authorization

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

I have a specific situation. My ISP shut off my Internet connection due to a high bill (parents haven't paid monthly rates and it added up). As I need Internet connection on a daily basis, I got myself a mobile broadband USB stick. As I wanted to keep using WiFi on my mobile, I used the ISP provided router and I enabled sharing on my broadband stick, so I can connect over wifi to my mobile broadband Internet.

As I wasn't able to change the password on my WiFi, and my neighbour knows it, I kept using the one that was set before. Today I decided to change the password on my wifi but due to the fact that normal Internet is disconnected, my router can't obtain a default gateway address (at least that is what I think for now, I'm not sure how it actually works). That means that I am unable to access router settings page and therefor I can't change my wifi password. My mobile broadband internet is not flat rate, so it's kind of an issue if someone else uses that connection as it can result in high bills.

To sum up, is there a way to somehow obtain a default gateway address so I can access my settings page, or is there any type of software that could enable some kind of authorization on my network?

I am using Win8 64bit.

ipconfig /all

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\xyz>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Home
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Mobile Broadband adapter Mobile broadband:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : AlcatelOTDC Wireless Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-A0-C6-00-00-12
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c0bc:697e:9ce0:95ad%14(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.200.150.223(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.192
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 8. siječnja 2015. 16:18:27
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 8. siječnja 2015. 18:18:27
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.200.150.193
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.200.150.193
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 335585478
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1B-FA-08-17-00-25-22-36-9B-3D

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 195.29.166.120
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-25-22-36-9B-3D
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::fc94:6de:726:3e03%12(Preferred)
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.62.3(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{13054755-17A5-43AA-AF6F-CF262960E435}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{51B6F1B9-9226-4248-BFD2-0D4AB2331029}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

C:\Users\xyz>
```

Comment: Default gateway of the router? Cable in to the router and run ipconfig?

Comment: I know, it's empty on that field. Tried ipconfig and ipconfig /all with the same result. edit: added the output to the question

Comment: Just to confirm.. so you have a broadband stick that is attached to your computer through usb and then the router is connected to the computer?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I'm using wifi on a daily basis with that setup.

Comment: Plug in then run an IP scanner, try browsing to the IP's until you hit the router login page. Most  IP scanners have the hardware names of the device so you may well see your router model. The IP address of the router will be the default gateway.

Comment: You should able to open the router page using the default ip like 192.168.1.1, if your router connected through wire with your computer....., You can change the password only if you pull the router page.. You can contact your ISP for default IP address